# How can I get syntax highlighting for cgo (golang)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, cgo

cgo is written in "comments" in go which means by default it's given comment syntax highlighting. It would be nice have proper golang *and* C syntax highlighting but within cgo files.

```
package main

// ... C code or #include here ...
import "C"

... Go code here ...
```

[Example](https://github.com/AlekSi/cgo-by-example/blob/master/main.go#L4)

I'd like this for either Visual Studio Code, or ViM.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can add cgo file extensions for syntax highlighting in your editor (vim, atom, vscode, etc). What is your editor?

Comment: What editor are you using that has syntax highlighting for cgo?

Comment: I'm using atom it does provides syntax highlight for `.go`, `.c`, `.h`, etc.

Comment: I'm look for _more_ than just `.go` highlighting i'm looking for `cgo` which is c written in comments inside a go file. Example: https://github.com/AlekSi/cgo-by-example/blob/master/main.go#L4

Comment: I doubt, you will get one. Mostly syntax highlighter works using file extension in the editor. For `.go` ext it will treat it as go file. Good luck.

Comment: GoLand (IntelliJ's Go IDE) supports syntax highlighting for cgo C preamble comments (se [here](https://i.imgur.com/ETmrOcn.png)), so, I mean it's not "impossible" like everyone is saying. However I would love it it were available in VSCode since that's what I use for writing go.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to place the C code in a header file, for instance `example.h`, then in your Go program use:

```
// #include "example.h"
import "C"
```

When opening `example.h`, you get syntax highlighting.

Alternatively, for ViM, the [SyntaxRange](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SyntaxRange) plugin can supposedly highlight C code that is part of Go code, but it may not be straightforward to configure.

Answer (score 1):

I woul say that, depending on your editor this is somewhere between impossible, and pointlessly difficult.

The only way you can tell the difference between a normal comment block and one used by cgo, is that the cgo block is immediately followed by `import "C"`. Depending on how the syntax highlighting lexer for your editor is constructed it may or may not be able to detect this.

A possible partial solution would be to write a simplified subset of the C highlighter that only effects obvious code, then apply that to all comment blocks. Not a very good solution, but better than nothing.

Good luck!